# How to change web server from iis to cassini without loading project to VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, cassini

I want to change webserver of a project from IIS to cassini. I can't load my web project to VS. VS gives this error:

[image]

Can I change webserver option without loading project.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Is this really a Web project ? Or simply a library ?

Comment: Does this lack of Web tab occur for any Web project or just this one ? If for any Web project, you may need to repair VS.

Comment: Web tab occur for just this one.

Comment: Actually, I have to edit my question because I can't load project and VS says, "unable to open the web site http://..." IIS is not installed on this computer...

Comment: Setting the Web server in the project settings is only useful within VS. So if you can't open it in VS, you don't need to do this. If you have IIS somewhere, just copy the aspx/bin/etc files to the right directory or creat a virtual directory where the files are already.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5101/discussion-between-cagin-and-timores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web project files in Visual Studio are Xml files. Consequently, IIS vs Cassini settings are stored in plain sight Xml. You can programmatically modify them using only any Xml api.

There is an example of such a work here: [Programmatically change Web project settings from dynamic port to static](http://blog-rat.blogspot.com/2009/05/programmatically-change-project.html), although it's not changing the web server type, it's exactly the same idea.